# Python - Averaging out histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have 4 histograms in Python, however I want to create a 5th histogram that is the average of the first four histograms (sum the frequencies for each bin and divide by 4). Is there any way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Elevations1 = np.zeros(100)
Elevations2 = np.zeros(100)
Elevations3 = np.zeros(100)
Elevations4 = np.zeros(100)

for a in np.arange(len(Elevations1)):

    Elevations1[a] = random.randrange(-10000, 10000)
    Elevations2[a] = random.randrange(-10000, 10000)
    Elevations3[a] = random.randrange(-10000, 10000)
    Elevations4[a] = random.randrange(-10000, 10000)

 plt.figure(1)
 plt.hist(Elevations1)
 plt.figure(2)
 plt.hist(Elevations2)
 plt.figure(3)
 plt.hist(Elevations3)
 plt.figure(4)
 plt.hist(Elevations4)
```

Comment: Yes. Are they NumPy arrays? Lists? What have you tried, do you have any code?

Comment: add your code and data please. it is possible yes

Comment: Ok can do, now I want to create a fifth histogram that is the average of each of the other 4 histograms.

Comment: add the full code.. what is Planet_Elevations1 ??

Comment: That should just be Elevations1, the for loop is looping through each position of the numpy arrays and giving it a random number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to average out the frequencies from each bin from each histogram.

Comment: @NEMM2020 My updated answer does what you asked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170970/discussion-between-seralouk-and-nemm2020).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to get the frequencies of the combined histogram and then normalize them by 4 to get the average. You can do the following:**

---

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(0)

Elevations1 = np.zeros(100)
Elevations2 = np.zeros(100)
Elevations3 = np.zeros(100)
Elevations4 = np.zeros(100)

for a in np.arange(len(Elevations1)):

    Elevations1[a] = random.randrange(-10000, 10000)
    Elevations2[a] = random.randrange(-10000, 10000)
    Elevations3[a] = random.randrange(-10000, 10000)
    Elevations4[a] = random.randrange(-10000, 10000)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(Elevations1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Elevations2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(Elevations3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(Elevations4)

df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], ignore_index=True)

# Get the frequencies of the combined histogram
hist, bins = np.histogram(df_merged)
# Normalize by 4
hist_norm = hist / 4.0


width = 0.9 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2

# plot the Un-normalited frequencies
plt.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
plt.title('Non- Normalized Histogram')
plt.show()

# plot the normalized frequencies
plt.bar(center, hist_norm, align='center', width=width)
plt.title('Normalized Histogram')
plt.show()
```

---

[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: This is pretty good, but this adds the frequency from each histogram.I want to average out the frequency of each bin from each histogram.

Comment: Oh.okay now i understand. I will update my answer in a few minutes

Comment: Minor nitpick, might want to use something like `df_merged.hist(edgecolor='black')` to show dividers between columns in case some are the same height.

Comment: Can do, it does look a lot better. Thanks

Comment: What does random.seed(0) at the beginning do? Also I am getting a value error "weights should have the same shape as x"

Comment: random.seed(0) just defines a seed for the random generator so now you can get the same random values every time you run the code. I updated my answer. I think this is what you want

Comment: Ok sounds good! Is there any advantage to using the numpy histogram? I usually use the PyPlot histogram

Comment: In this case, the numpy histogram allows us to get the `hist` and `bins`and then we can easily normalize the `hist` (frequencies). For your goal, this is the best way I believe. If the answer works please upvote and accept it. I have already upvoted your question.

Comment: I have been double checking your work but I don't think it takes the average of each frequency of each histogram.

Comment: When I plot each histogram, add up all the frequencies and divide by 4, I don't get the average frequency I should see on the averaged histogram for each bin.

Comment: If you plot each histogram separately, and look at the first bin you will see the following values: 12,18,8 and 6. The average of these is 11 as shown in the first bin of my normalized histogram. I believe the code is correct and does what you want. Make sure that you use the same code as in my answer and the same seed .